# Doctrine Mongo ODM find in array

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to build a query that filters for the elements of the roles array. I need the users who have the role admin or the role user. This is (a part of) my document:

```
{
    "username": "test_joe",
    "email": "joe@joe.joe",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [
        "admin",
        "user",
        "guest"
    ]
}
```

I tried something like this, but this is not the correct one:

```
$qb = $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder('user')
        ->select('email');

$qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('roles.admin')->exists(true));
$qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('roles.user')->exists(true));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no field `roles.admin` in your document. It's field `"roles"` with array of values. MongoDB matching is polymorphic on arrays so you can match just like you having field `"roles": "admin"`
So you don't need exists but something like `->field('roles')->equals('admin')`